# Check if a command line argument is an integer

Tags: c, validation, command-line-arguments

I have to check if given argument is integer or not. I can't use [] and memory allocation, i tried using isdigit(); but its not working for me.
Thanks for any advices and help.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int sum=0, i;

    if(argc<2)
    {
        printf("Not enough arguments");
        return 9;
    }
    for (i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(atoi(*(argv+i))))
        {
            printf("Incorrect input");
            return 1;
        }
    }   
    for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        sum+=atoi(*(argv+i));
    }

    printf("%d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

It should show "Incorrect input" and return 1 if one of numbers aren't integer, but when i'm using isdigit everytime programs prints "Incorrect input" even when all numbers are integers.

Comment: `isdigit` operates on a *character*. You should call it **before** calling `atoi()` (because you wouldn't want to call `atoi()` with a non-digit character).

Comment: Use [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) for the conversion and the validation is built-in.

Comment: Also, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i` the expression `*(p + 1)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter is usually easier to read and understand, as well as a little less to write.

Answer (score 1):

> to check if given argument is integer or not.

Use `strto*()` family of functions. [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)

Example: Test if `int`?

```
bool is_int(const char *arg) {
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long value = strtol(arg, &endptr, 10);

  // Various tests, adjust as desired.

  if (arg == endptr) return false; // no conversion occurred.
  if (errno == ERANGE) return false; // outside `long` range
  if (value > INT_MAX || value < INT_MIN) return false; // outside `int` range
  if (*endptr != '\0') return false; // Extra junk at end

  return true;
}



  for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
    if (!is_int(argv+i)) {
      printf("Incorrect input\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

Research [`strtol()`](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=c+strtol&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for more details.

---

Alternatively one could simply look for an optional sign followed by digits if *any* integer is OK, even big ones.

```
bool is_integer(const char *arg) {
  if (*arg == '-' || *arg == '+') arg++;

  bool digit_found = false;
  while (isdigit((unsigned char) *arg)) {
     arg++;
     digit_found = true;
  }

  return *arg == '\0' && digit_found;
}
```

---

`atoi(*(argv+i))` should generate a warning.  Enable all warnings to save time.  `atoi()` expects a pointer to a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped and now everything is working fine